# Send Current URL link to A Discord Webhook

Tags: php, html, discord, webhooks

So, basically I need a way to send the current URL link to A Discord webhook.

So for example, the URL would be https://www.example.com and I need that link to send to my Discord webhook.

Is there any way someone could help me with this? If this is not possible, are there any alternative methods?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you first reading [this](https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/index.html)—it explains in detail how to format the `payload` so that it renders as a message in Discord properly, you can even use markdown!

Second, I'm not sure what language you want to code this in, but here's a simple example using `Python` and `httpx`

The idea to take away here is

1. Pick a client library
2. Study the Discord webhook message format
3. Create a client for HTTP
4. Set the logic to send the payload to the webhook you want
5. Create and send the payload with the formatted webhook message in a `POST` request

```py
data = {
  "username": "Webhook",
  "avatar_url": "https://i.imgur.com/4M34hi2.png",
  "content": "Text message. Up to 2000 characters.",
  "embeds": [
    {
      "author": {
        "name": "Birdie♫",
        "url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/cats/",
        "icon_url": "https://i.imgur.com/R66g1Pe.jpg"
      },
      "title": "Title",
      "url": "https://google.com/",
      "description": "Text message. You can use Markdown here. *Italic* **bold** __underline__ ~~strikeout~~ [hyperlink](https://google.com) `code`",
      "color": 15258703,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Text",
          "value": "More text",
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Even more text",
          "value": "Yup",
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "Use `\"inline\": true` parameter, if you want to display fields in the same line.",
          "value": "okay..."
        },
        {
          "name": "Thanks!",
          "value": "You're welcome :wink:"
        }
      ],
      "thumbnail": {
        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1_ukaavUI.jpg"
      },
      "image": {
        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/A_picture_from_China_every_day_108.jpg"
      },
      "footer": {
        "text": "Woah! So cool! :smirk:",
        "icon_url": "https://i.imgur.com/fKL31aD.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}

import httpx # pip install httpx, or poetry add httpx

with httpx.Client() as client:
    request = client.post("https://www.discordwebhook.com", data=data) # needs to be a POST
    print(request.status_code)
```

Comment: That's great! I'll make sure to read the guide, but the script you provided is in python, for what I am currently working on, I need php and/or html.

Comment: I added a comment regarding the logical steps you need to takeaway, you can implement this using any language or framework you want. Read my answer once more with the added steps